# CMS List pages except the 404 page

Tags: magento

On my magento website, I can display a list of all my CMS Pages with this method :

```
Mage::getModel('cms/page')->getCollection()
```

But now I'd like to hide the 404 page in my list for example. How to do that ?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default the 404 cms page has the identifier `no-route`. You can get the collection like this:

```
$pages = Mage::getModel('cms/page')->getCollection()
    ->addFieldToFilter('identifier', array('neq'=>'no-route'));
```

But Magento offers the possibility to make any page the 404 page. So the cleaner approach would be to get the real 404 page identifier first.

```
$_errPage = Mage::getStoreConfig('web/default/cms_no_route');
$parts = explode('|', $_errPage);
$identifier = $parts[0];
$pages = Mage::getModel('cms/page')->getCollection()
        ->addFieldToFilter('identifier', array('neq'=>$identifier));
```

I also recommend adding a store filter so you get only the pages enabled on the current store:

```
$pages = Mage::getModel('cms/page')->getCollection()
        ->addStoreFilter(Mage::app()->getStore()->getId())
        ->addFieldToFilter('identifier', array('neq'=>$identifier));
```